# Saving files on a Mac computer

Tags: mac, save, files

I previously had a PC computer, where I could easily save QGIS files to any folder I wanted through the browse tool under "Save As".  However, I have since switched to a Mac and when I try to save my files to a custom folder, it  only shows a select few folder options instead of allowing me to browse to the folder that I want to save the files in.  Has anyone else experienced this problem and figured out a solution?

Comment: Doubt this is a QGIS problem and more a Mac file system / GUI problem... can you post a screen capture (if you can navigate the elaborate keyboard shortcut)?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the "Browse" button on the "Save vector layer as ..." dialog window you should be presented with the file manager window, which on a Mac is the Finder app.  Navigation is a bit different than on MS Windows, but there should be about three panes on this Finder window that will let you navigate up/down the folder tree to get to the folder you wish to save your files in. If you do not see these panes you may need to click on the drop-down arrow next to Save As input box and/or there is also there is an up/down arrow in the current folder box that you may need to click to navigate to a higher folder. If you need a new folder you need to navigate to the folder it will be stored in and then click the "New Folder" button.  Knowing the version of your Mac OS and QGIS would be helpful to ensure a more complete answer.